# Cannot Convert Pandas Time Column to Date Time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Example of the values in df column ['time']:

```
'2021-10-06 20:00:00'
'2021-10-06 19:45:00'
'2021-10-06 19:30:00'
```

CODE IVE TRIED WITH ERRORS

```
*** for i in df['time']:
    datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], infer_datetime_format = True)****

ERROR RECEIVED - time data 'time' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

It works when I do use .loc and use a single row and use the same syntax. Please help me understand what is causing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(data.dtypes)
data.head()
```

Output:

```
time    object
dtype: object
                   time
0   2021-10-06 20:00:00
1   2021-10-06 19:45:00
2   2021-10-06 19:30:00
```

Then:

```
data['time'] = data['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print(data.dtypes)
data.head()
```

Output:

```
time    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
                   time
0   2021-10-06 20:00:00
1   2021-10-06 19:45:00
2   2021-10-06 19:30:00
```

**Update:**

Comparison with `pd.to_datetime` using a dataset with 2K rows:

datetime.strptime:

```
%%time
def test1():
  result = np.array(data['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
  return len(result)
timeit.timeit(test1, number=1000)

CPU times: user 11.1 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 11.1 s
Wall time: 11.1 s
11.05006343498826
```

pd.to_datetime:

```
%%time

def test2():
  result = np.array(pd.to_datetime(data['time'], format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
  return len(result)

timeit.timeit(test2, number=1000)

CPU times: user 775 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 775 ms
Wall time: 774 ms
0.773764010053128
```

So yes, use `pd.to_datetime`.

Alternatively, you can use it on load:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', 
                    converters={'time': pd.to_datetime})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I get the same thing. --------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError: time data 'time' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: It has to do with the way I read in multiple csvs. Thanks ...

Comment: I suggest not to use Python 's datetime here at all, just `pd.to_datetime`.